# Connected component of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory

The set of $n\times n$ matrices can be identified with the space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I would like to show that the set of matrices that can be joined to the identity $I$ forms a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: You mean the path component of $I$ in $G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\gamma:[0,1]\to G$ is a path, $\gamma(0)=g$, $\gamma(1)=1$, then $\gamma'(t):=h\gamma(t)h^{-1}$ is a path from $hgh^{-1}$ to $1$. Your set is thus invariant wrt. conjugations. To see that it is a subgroup, if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma _2$ are two paths, consider the new path $\gamma(t):=\gamma_1(t)\gamma_2(t)$ (so it's closed under product), or $\gamma(t)=\gamma_1(t)^{-1}$ (closed under inverse).

Comment: Why did you consider a path going towards G and not I ?

Comment: @Carpediem: I edited to use the same direction as in the question (it certainly doesn't matter)

Comment: Well in my solution I should write that $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow I$ no ?

Comment: @Carpediem: do you understand what that notation means? A parametrised curve is a function from $[0,1]$ (the parameter space) to $G$ (the space the curve lies in)$.

Comment: @user8268 What is h ?

Comment: @Carpediem any element of $G$

Answer (score 2):

This is true for any topological group $G$ : The basic idea is that the two maps
$$
R_g : x \mapsto xg \text{ and } L_g : x\mapsto gx
$$
are both homeomorphisms.

Let $K$ be the connected component of the identity, then for any $x \in K$,
$$
Kx^{-1} = R_{x^{-1}}(K)
$$
is connected (since it is the image of $K$ under a homeomorphism) and contains $e=xx^{-1}$. Hence,
$$
Kx^{-1} \subset K \Rightarrow KK^{-1} \subset K
$$
Hence, $K$ is a subgroup.

Furthermore, if $g\in G$, then
$$
gKg^{-1} = R_{g^{-1}}L_g(K)
$$
is connected and contains the identity. Hence $gKg^{-1} \subset K$, and hence $K$ is normal.

Comment: Could you present an answer regarding the path-connected component of I rather than just the connected component?

Comment: The OP asked for an answer regarding the path-connected component of I rather than just the connected component

Comment: @Carpediem : I misunderstood your question because of the title, and was not sure if "joined" meant path component or just connected.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Can you modify the answer based on my question ?

Comment: I believe @user8268 has answered your question. I am not sure I can add anything substantial to that!